# How to use REGEXP_LIKE for all columns in a tables?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

As part of my report, I wrote a code with 15 sub-quires in select statement to fetch details. As I am perform sum of these 15 columns i am receiving invalid Value Error. My guess was that one of the column might contain special character.

So I am using condition `NOT REGEXP_LIKE(Column_name,'\d')` to get rows which have special characters. As there are 15 columns, I want help to check this condition for all columns in a single shot.

```
WHRER NOT REGEXP_LIKE(Column_name,'\d')
```

Should give rows in which has special characters in any column.

Answer (score 1):

Use `OR`:

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(col1,'\D') 
   OR REGEXP_LIKE(col2,'\D') 
  ...
   OR REGEXP_LIKE(col15,'\D')
```

or concat the data:

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(col1||col2||...||col15,'\D')
```

You have to check for non-digit values therefore \D instead of \d as `REGEXP_LIKE(col1,'\d')` returns true for any string that contains at least one digit (`A54` for example).

Answer (score 0):

I would say you have a problem with your query or data model if you are doing arithmetic on string values.  That sounds like a problem.

But to answer your question.  This conditional expression:

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(Column_name, '\d')
```

returns true when the column has at least one digit character.

```
WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(Column_name, '\d')
```

returns true when the column has no digits.

I think the logic you want to detect a number is actually:

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(Column_name, '^\d+$')
```

I would recommend doing this logic separately for each column:

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(Col1, '^\d+$') AND
      REGEXP_LIKE(Col2, '^\d+$') AND
      . . .
```

This works for *digits* but it does not handle negative signs, decimal points, or `NULL` values.

For the particular purpose of digits, you can concatenate the columns:

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(Col1 || Col2 || . . ., '^\d+$')
```